# Can I use three-dimensional compute shader to write to a three-dimensional image

Tags: opengl, glsl

**define a three-dimensional Texture and dispatch compute**

```
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 1, GL_RGBA32F, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, TEXTURE_DEPTH);

glBindImageTexture(0, m_Texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);

glDispatchCompute(16, 16, 2);
```

**compute shader**

```
#version 450

layout(local_size_x = 32,local_size_y = 32, local_size_z = 2) in;

layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image3D Image;

void main()
{
    ivec3 position = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xyz);
    vec4 color = vec4(gl_WorkGroupID / vec3(gl_NumWorkGroups), 1.0);
    imageStore(Image, position, color);
}
```

**but the code doesn't work, I want to konw the value of gl_GlobalInvocationID.z is the depth  of space**

Comment: is the value of gl_GlobalInvocationID.xyz corresponding to the Texture coordinates

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: The resolution is 511*512,it is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this probelm, the parameters of glDispatchCompute() is x,y,z, ifx*y*z*local_size_x*local_size_y*local_size_z > screensize.x*screensize.y, it cannot work, so I downsample the texture resolution.